# Pythagorean "Lemma"

Tags: terminology

It is known that a theorem is a crucial result that solves many problems in a given field, and a lemma is a claim that holds for proving other important results.

We all know the Pythagoras Theorem, and we know that this theorem helps us prove a lot of other more complex claims. Then why don't we call it the Pythagorean Lemma but the Pythagorean Theorem?

Comment: In my experience, the distinction between lemmas and theorems tends to be more historical than anything else, cf. Zorn's Lemma vs. the Well-ordering Theorem.

Comment: In Book I of Euclid's *Elements*, the Triangle Inequality is the 20th proposition and is used as a lemma for proving the 47th proposition, the Pythagorean Theorem. There is no formal distinction between lemmas and theorems. The only difference is intent.

Answer (score 3):

A theorem is an important statement in mathematics on its own, while a lemma's main/sole purpose is proving a theorem.

The Pythagorean Theorem is an important result in mathematics, and we should not call it a lemma just because it has many profound consequences. Quite the contrary, in fact, that is a reason we should call it a theorem.